# Can I update a module on end user's machine without npm or node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, electron

I'm developing an electron application and a module and an electron application uses a module that I made. but I really want to update a module on end user's machine when the target module has new version even if their machine ***hasn't installed*** NPM or node environment.

In conclusion, my question is: Can I update a module for an electron application on end user's machine even if NPM or Node environment ***hasn't installed*** on their computer?

Update: The module that I want to update is ***node.js addon*** and the binary is published and installed on end user's machine by node-pre-gyp, I can't use any of CDN because it's addon.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick solution : you can keep the module file (.js minified/uglified) in a remote cdn and then access that file at client's end. Whenever you want to update , you can just replace the file.

Comment: I'm sorry about it, The module that I want to update is node.js addon. I can't use any of CDN because of addon binary.

Comment: So what you are trying to do is update a node.js addon without the npm installed? I am not quite sure about that.

Comment: Yes, That's what I want to do.

Comment: You can make wrapper at your end using that addon and then upload that to the cdn.